CSS selector for adding style to nth-child(even) does not work for dynamically added table rows - Is this a bug in HTML/CSS rendering?
I am playing around with adding content from an array to a table on my page that in code, only has a header row, and a CSS selector which sets the container div to "display:none;".  Immediately after the table declaraton, I created a small script on my HTML page which is dynamically adding rows to a table like so:
<div id="div-load">
  <h1>Popular Disney Characters by Merchandise Sales</h1>
  <table id="table-fill" class="table-style">
    <tr>
      <th>Character</th>
      <th>Rank</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    let characters = ["Mickey Mouse", "Minnie Mouse", "Goofy", "Donald Duck", "Pluto"];
    let charTable = document.getElementById("div-load");
    for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
      let charRank = i + 1;
      let   tr = "<tr><td>" + characters[i] + "</td><td style=\'text-align:center;\'>" +     charRank + "</td></tr>";
      document.getElementById("table-fill").innerHTML += tr;
    }
    if (characters.length > 0) {
      charTable.style["display"] = "block";
    }
  </script>
</div>


I also have the following CSS selector to color the rows of the table:
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #76d0c0;
}

I have other selectors which apply to this table and those are being applied correctly to both this dynamically created one, and another statically created table on the page, so I will ignore those for the context of this issue...
Anyway, when I load the page with an empty array, my if statement returns false as expected, and the page is not on the screen. When I add values to the array, I'm finding that the background-color attribute is not being applied to the rows, I'm adding, so I get the following result:

But if I change my CSS selector to just "tr", then I get this result:

As you can see in the images, the tr selector is being properly applied to the static table, so I'm discounting a bug in the CSS selector for now. Is there a bug in the way nth-child is processed when it comes to dynamic content, or is there a preferred way to implement nth-child styling dynamically? I suppose I could add logic to my script to add the style inline, but considering that dynamic styling works otherwise, it feels inefficient.
As mentioned above, simply commenting out the nth-child specification applied he expected styling dynamically, so I'm just a little confused as to why nth-child fails. I also verified that this behaves the same in Chrome and Edge browsers.

Have you tried using document.createElement(), rather than appending to the innerHTML

You create one <tr> for each <tbody> element, so there are no even elements for the selector to match. Did you perhaps try tr:nth-child(odd) (JS Fiddle demo) to compare?

as @David Thomas said  you don't have even tr as you only have one tr per tbody

This is exactly the same issue. If you must use innerHTML, loop through and add to a string each time then set innerHTML at the end

Thank you all. I was playing around with createElement for a bit, but wound up with the implementation above. After seeing what @DavidThomas and Adam posted, I will give that a try. I inadvertently created and added a table all in one shot on another page that I was working on this morning, and noticed that the styling effects did get applied to the table, so I believe that the approach suggested is the correct one.

Confirmed - made the change in the loop as suggested by @Adam to build the innerHTML all at once and assign to innerHTML in one shot and it worked. Thanks again everyone.
